# How to pass nested collection within JavaScript remoting

Tags: remote-action, remote-objects

I'm trying to pass collection to overrided SObjectModel update function. 
If I pass primitives, I can get them in APEX. But if I pass nested collection, I got Unhandled Exception:

> FATAL_ERROR System.UnexpectedException: null

VF:

```
<apex:remoteObjectModel name="TopicAssignment" fields="Id" 
    update="{!$RemoteAction.ROT.updateNew}"/>
...
var topicIds = ['0FT7A0000008WlWWAU', '0FT7A0000008WlWWKl'];
new SObjectModel.TopicAssignment().update([<Array of IDS>],
    {mode:'saveTAssignment',plus:topicIds},callback);
```

Apex:

```
@RemoteAction
public static Map<String, Object> updateNew
    (String type, List<String> recordIds, Map<String, Object> fieldMap) { 
        String mode = (String)fieldMap.get('mode');//works fine
        fieldMap.get('plus')//throws exception
        JSON.deserialize(fieldMap.get('plus'),List<Id>.class)//throws exception
```

How to get the list or map or any JS object/literal passed in the remote object override call?

Comment: The way I read your error message, it appears that you can either have a plus array, a minus array, or both. Since you had a minus array and got the null exception, were you trying to remove that ID? You say you get the error only when passing an array. Please show us how you pass a single record sucessfully.

Comment: @crmprogdev Think about a best case scenario where I am always passing all the values and still showing Error. Updated question how the ids are getting passed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remote Method Overrides in Remote Objects [example](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_remote_objects_example_overrides.htm) uses `Map<String, Object>` as third parameter in RemoteAction. That's useful, because we could send any primitive or any collection of primitives as an `Object` and deserialize it properly in Apex.

In your JS you're sending `list<id>` as an `Object`, apex could not deserialize collection automatically, that's why you have exception.
You should serialize it with `JSON.stringify` or send plain string:

```
var ids = ['0FT3600000005cW', '0FT3600000005cZ'];
var plusIds = JSON.stringify(['0FT3600000005cY', '0FT3600000005cQ']); 
var jsonObj = '{"employees":[{"firstName":"John"},{"firstName":"Peter"}],
    "comments":[{"note":"stringify"}]}';
var ctDetails = {mode:'saveTAssignment',plus:plusIds,minus:jsonObj}  
var topicassignment = new SObjectModel.TopicAssignment().update(ids, ctDetails);
```

Deserialize in Apex:

```
list<String> ids =(List<String>)System.JSON.deserialize((string)fieldMap.get('plus'),List<String>.class);
Map<String,Object> objectMap = (Map<String,Object>)System.JSON.deserializeUntyped((String)fieldMap.get('minus'));
system.debug(objectMap.get('employees'));
system.debug(ids);
```

Debug:

```
DEBUG|(0FT3600000005cY, 0FT3600000005cQ)
DEBUG|({firstName=John}, {firstName=Peter})
```

Comment: I was using object coz the Map not always has List of strings sometimes it has List<object> sometimes sting etc, based on what APEX Object was build for to support datatype "ANY" internally. So I guess I have to use Object. The object can be cast to a list or string or Integer, isn't it the case

Comment: you can pass any json object within pair (string,object):
plus:'John',
plus:'{FirstName:"John", LastName: "Doe"}'
plus:'{"employees":[
    {"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe"},
    {"firstName":"Anna", "lastName":"Smith"},
    {"firstName":"Peter", "lastName":"Jones"}
]}'
and parse them accordlingly in apex

Comment: Please go through the question I am able to pass the multiple objects and the Map is displaying fine in System debug and in user debug when I want to print and .get() any key it gives me a System Exception(only if it is a JS object/Array, else it is fine for all primitive type). If I do .containsKey() it returns true

Comment: you should deserialize your string to collection of objects in class. I've added list<id> in answer

Comment: or try [this](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/106309/deserialize-json-to-sobject)

Comment: Thanks a lot stringify did the trick but it was a pretty bad programming hack searching and looking up types since I had a lot of dynamic variables, I hardcoded some type to beat that not I am passing a string then desrializing the whole string into Map<String,Object> and then the object is sometimes a list<Object> sometimes it is a string and sometimes a List<Map>. Can't post the solution not a good program. But the idea is yours.